# Urlrewrite regex based on parameter

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite strings of this form:

```
"/folder/default.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3" (example)
```

to

```
"/newfolder/?a=1&b=2&c=3"
```

if url contains "`a=1`"

Im using UrlRewritingNet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rewrites>
    <add name="SomeRuleNameHere" 
         virtualUrl="^~/folder/default\.aspx\?(.*&amp;)?a=1(&amp;.*)?$"
         destinationUrl="~/newfolder/?$1a=1$2"
         ignoreCase="true"
         rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" />
</rewrites>
```